# PySFTP connection works but get() fails

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I can setup a connection with `pysftp` but i can not get `s.get()` to work.

The connection works fine:

```
import pysftp
s = pysftp.Connection(host="xxx", username="xxx", password="xxx")
```

I can also work with `s.chdir("/path/to/target")` and show the file i want to grab via `s.listdir()` and receive `True` for `s.isfile("/path/to/target/file.xxx")`.

Yet, executing `s.get("/path/to/target/file.xxx")` yields `IOError: Folder not found: C:\some\other\folder\file.xxx`. Note that the original `/path/to/target/` (which is also shown in a SFTP client like WinSCP) now appears to point to a different folder with Windows syntax.

Traceback:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-9d6fc4a6dd9d> in <module>()
----> 1 s.get(r'/path/to/target/file.xxx')

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\pysftp.pyc in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback, preserve_mtime)
    231             sftpattrs = self._sftp.stat(remotepath)
    232 
--> 233         self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
    234         if preserve_mtime:
    235             os.utime(localpath, (sftpattrs.st_atime, sftpattrs.st_mtime))

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.pyc in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback)
    718         file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size
    719         with open(localpath, 'wb') as fl:
--> 720             size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
    721         s = os.stat(localpath)
    722         if s.st_size != size:

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.pyc in getfo(self, remotepath, fl, callback)
    688         with self.open(remotepath, 'rb') as fr:
    689             file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size
--> 690             fr.prefetch()
    691             size = 0
    692             while True:

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.pyc in prefetch(self)
    394         .. versionadded:: 1.5.1
    395         """
--> 396         size = self.stat().st_size
    397         # queue up async reads for the rest of the file
    398         chunks = []

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.pyc in stat(self)
    237         :return: an `.SFTPAttributes` object containing attributes about this file.
    238         """
--> 239         t, msg = self.sftp._request(CMD_FSTAT, self.handle)
    240         if t != CMD_ATTRS:
    241             raise SFTPError('Expected attributes')

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.pyc in _request(self, t, *arg)
    727     def _request(self, t, *arg):
    728         num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)
--> 729         return self._read_response(num)
    730 
    731     def _async_request(self, fileobj, t, *arg):

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.pyc in _read_response(self, waitfor)
    774                 # synchronous
    775                 if t == CMD_STATUS:
--> 776                     self._convert_status(msg)
    777                 return t, msg
    778             if fileobj is not type(None):

C:\Miniconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.pyc in _convert_status(self, msg)
    804             raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
    805         else:
--> 806             raise IOError(text)
    807 
    808     def _adjust_cwd(self, path):
IOError: Folder not found: C:\some\other\folder\file.xxx
```

Log from a successful download with WinSCP:

```
[...]
. 2014-10-09 10:39:22.146 Listing directory "/path/to/target".
> 2014-10-09 10:39:22.146 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 77, Number: 3595
< 2014-10-09 10:39:22.146 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 3332
. 2014-10-09 10:39:22.146 Discarding reserved response
< 2014-10-09 10:39:22.332 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 12, Number: 3595
> 2014-10-09 10:39:22.333 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 3852
< 2014-10-09 10:39:22.518 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 1043, Number: 3852
> 2014-10-09 10:39:22.650 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 4108
< 2014-10-09 10:39:22.785 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 4108
< 2014-10-09 10:39:22.786 Status code: 1
> 2014-10-09 10:39:22.786 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 12, Number: 4356
. 2014-10-09 10:39:22.786 ..;D;0;2013-11-05T06:20:22.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];r-x------;0
[...]
. 2014-10-09 10:39:22.786 file.xxx;-;3087870;2014-10-09T00:00:13.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];r-x------;0
[...]
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.310 File: '/path/to/target/file.xxx' [2014-10-09T00:00:13.000Z] [3087870]
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.322 Copying "/path/to/target/file.xxx" to local directory started.
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.322 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.344 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.344 Opening remote file.
> 2014-10-09 10:39:27.344 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 129, Number: 4611
< 2014-10-09 10:39:27.344 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 4356
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.344 Discarding reserved response
< 2014-10-09 10:39:27.518 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 12, Number: 4611
> 2014-10-09 10:39:27.518 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 16, Number: 4872
< 2014-10-09 10:39:27.658 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 112, Number: 4872
. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.770 Confirming overwriting of file.


. 2014-10-09 10:39:27.781 Asking user:

[...]

> 2014-10-09 10:39:30.736 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 24, Number: 5125
< 2014-10-09 10:39:40.496 Status code: 1
. 2014-10-09 10:39:40.539 222 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2014-10-09 10:39:40.539 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 12, Number: 34052
< 2014-10-09 10:39:40.539 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 33285
< 2014-10-09 10:39:40.632 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 33541
< 2014-10-09 10:39:40.753 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 33797
. 2014-10-09 10:39:40.910 Preserving timestamp [2014-10-09T00:00:13.000Z]
. 2014-10-09 10:41:10.393 Closing connection.
. 2014-10-09 10:41:10.393 Sending special code: 12
. 2014-10-09 10:41:10.393 Sent EOF message
```

Log from SFTP-3 WinSCP Download:

```
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.882 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.883 WinSCP Version 5.5.1 (Build 3970) [...]
[...]
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 SFTP Server: default
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 Local directory: C:\Users, Remote directory: /path/to/target/somefolder, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 DST mode: 1; Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2014-10-10 10:39:36.884 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.049 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.050 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.050 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2014-10-10 10:39:51.104 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2014-10-10 10:39:51.256 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.256 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.256 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.256 We will use UTF-8 strings when appropriate
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.268 Changing directory to "/path/to/target/somefolder".
. 2014-10-10 10:39:51.268 Getting real path for '/path/to/target/somefolder'
> 2014-10-10 10:39:51.268 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 41, Number: 16
< 2014-10-10 10:39:53.424 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 141, Number: 16
. 2014-10-10 10:39:53.424 Real path is '/path/to/target/somefolder'
. 2014-10-10 10:39:53.424 Trying to open directory "/path/to/target/somefolder".
> 2014-10-10 10:39:53.424 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 41, Number: 263
< 2014-10-10 10:39:53.594 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 21, Number: 263
. 2014-10-10 10:39:53.594 Getting current directory name.
. 2014-10-10 10:39:53.743 Listing directory "/path/to/target/somefolder".
> 2014-10-10 10:39:53.743 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 41, Number: 523
< 2014-10-10 10:39:53.894 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 12, Number: 523
> 2014-10-10 10:39:53.894 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 780
< 2014-10-10 10:39:54.403 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 16407, Number: 780
> 2014-10-10 10:39:54.403 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 1036
< 2014-10-10 10:39:54.915 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 4111, Number: 1036
> 2014-10-10 10:39:54.916 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 1292
< 2014-10-10 10:39:55.067 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 1292
< 2014-10-10 10:39:55.067 Status code: 1
> 2014-10-10 10:39:55.067 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 12, Number: 1540
[...]
. 2014-10-10 10:39:55.164 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:23.673 Cached directory change via ".." to "/path/to/target".
. 2014-10-10 10:40:23.730 Getting current directory name.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:23.730 Listing directory "/path/to/target".
> 2014-10-10 10:40:23.730 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 32, Number: 1803
< 2014-10-10 10:40:23.730 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 1540
. 2014-10-10 10:40:23.731 Discarding reserved response
< 2014-10-10 10:40:23.927 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 12, Number: 1803
> 2014-10-10 10:40:24.022 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 2060
< 2014-10-10 10:40:26.323 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 1247, Number: 2060
> 2014-10-10 10:40:26.381 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 12, Number: 2316
< 2014-10-10 10:40:26.531 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 2316
< 2014-10-10 10:40:26.531 Status code: 1
> 2014-10-10 10:40:26.531 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 12, Number: 2564
[...]
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.716 File: '/path/to/target/otherfolder/file.xxx' [2014-10-10T00:00:10.000Z] [3087870]
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.742 Copying "/path/to/target/otherfolder/file.xxx" to local directory started.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.742 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.774 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.774 Opening remote file.
> 2014-10-10 10:40:47.774 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 128, Number: 3843
< 2014-10-10 10:40:47.774 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 3588
. 2014-10-10 10:40:47.774 Discarding reserved response
< 2014-10-10 10:40:47.993 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 12, Number: 3843
> 2014-10-10 10:40:48.179 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 12, Number: 4104
< 2014-10-10 10:40:48.335 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 112, Number: 4104
. 2014-10-10 10:40:48.336 Confirming overwriting of file.
. 2014-10-10 10:40:48.446 Asking user:
[...]
< 2014-10-10 10:41:10.204 Status code: 1
. 2014-10-10 10:41:10.241 222 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2014-10-10 10:41:10.241 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 12, Number: 33284
< 2014-10-10 10:41:10.347 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 32517
< 2014-10-10 10:41:10.347 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 32773
< 2014-10-10 10:41:10.669 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 33029
. 2014-10-10 10:41:10.812 Preserving timestamp [2014-10-10T00:00:10.000Z]
. 2014-10-10 10:42:26.145 Closing connection.
. 2014-10-10 10:42:26.195 Sending special code: 12
. 2014-10-10 10:42:26.196 Sent EOF message
```

Any  ideas?

Comment: Isn't the `C:\some\other\folder` your local working directory? I.e. doesn't the error refer to accessing/writing a local file, rather than reading a remote file?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: Unfortunately, no. First argument is the remote path. I just tried the same on a Ubuntu VM and receive the same Folder not found error.

Comment: Can you share a piece of log showing download of the file using WinSCP?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: Added a excerpt.

Comment: Paramiko succeeds opening the remote file, but fails when reading opened file attributes (the FSTAT request). Yet WinSCP does exactly the same, without an error. The error message with Windows-like path is indeed coming from the server. Did you check server-side logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not the admin of the server. Do not yet know if they will offer any support. Interestingly a call to `s.stat("/path/to/target/file.xxx")` does return `<SFTPAttributes: [ size=xxxx mode=xxxx atime=xxxx mtime=xxxx ]>` without fail.

Comment: Yes, even the `sftp_client.get()` calls `stat()` two times prior to opening the file without a problem. But `stat()` uses `STAT` request (retrieving statistics for given file path), not `FSTAT` (retrieving statistics for a handle of opened file). There can be a bug in server's implementation of `FSTAT`. Though still, WinSCP uses `FSTAT` and no problem occurs. There can be a difference in SFTP protocol version used. Can you check WinSCP log for entry like *"SFTP version 3 negotiated"*?

Comment: Yes, it is `SFTP version 4 negotiated.`.

Comment: Furthermore, in the WinSCP properties it says SSH Implementation says `WS_FTP-SSH_7.x.x`.

Comment: Ok, can you try to download the file using WinSCP again, but this time restricting it to version 3? See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp

Comment: I added another log. Worked again with WinSCP.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I found a higher-performance workaround that relies on monkey-patching the paramiko code. Again, this is not a great fix, but it gets me what I need. I'm trying to think of a way to fix this in a more general way and then commit it back to paramiko source.

Before I show you the code, please note, this relies on monkey-patching the paramiko library so that each call to SFTPFile.stat will always return the stat result for the last filename patched in with fake_stat.

**ONLY USE THIS IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING**

While it seems to work for a simple script downloading a single file once, I do not guarantee that will work for any more complex use cases.

```
import paramiko.sftp_file

with pysftp.Connection(host, username=self.user, password=self.password) as sftp:
        try:
            with sftp.cd(location):
                def fake_stat(sftpFile):                                                                                                                                                       
                    return sftpFile.sftp.stat(latest_file.filename)                                                                                                                            

                paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.stat = fake_stat                                                                                                                                   

                sftp.get(filename, out_filename)                                                                                                                 
            return self.filename    
        except Exception as e:
            logging.fatal(e.message)
            raise
```

---

I can confirm Martin's analysis: it is only the underlying stat call through paramiko that causes the error. One workaround I found was to manually perform the copy myself. Of course, this has the drawback of being really slow, as the prefetch call really helps cut down on roundtrip latency for each block.

```
MB = 1024
BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * MB


with pysftp.Connection(host, username=self.user, password=self.password) as sftp:
        try:
            with sftp.cd(location):
                with sftp.open(remote_filename) as remote, open(local_filename), 'w') as local:
                    result = chardet.detect(remote.read(BLOCK_SIZE))
                    encoding = result['encoding']
                    remote.seek(0)

                    if encoding == 'ascii':
                        # Ascii is the most gimped encoding there is.                                                                                                                      
                        # Latin1 is strictly better, because at least its byte-for-byte.                                                                                                   
                        # Apologies to purists.                                                                                                                                            
                        print 'using encoding latin1'
                        encoding = 'latin1'

                    while True:
                        buf = remote.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
                        if not buf:
                            break

                        line = codecs.decode(buf, encoding, 'replace')
                        local.write(codecs.encode(line, 'utf-8'))

                        if len(buf) < BLOCK_SIZE:
                            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.fatal(e.message)
            raise
```